# Divide by integer in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, arithmetic-division, combinatorial-logic

I need to divide an integer by an integer in one clock cycle.
How should I do this?
I have a function for it I found on the internet but it always returns one.

> ```
> function  divide  (a : unsigned; b : unsigned) return integer is
>     variable a1 : unsigned(15 downto 0):=a;
>     variable b1 : unsigned(15 downto 0):=a;
>     variable p1 : unsigned(16 downto 0):= (others => '0');
>     variable i : integer:=0;
>     begin
>         for i in 0 to b'length-1 loop
>             p1(b'length-1 downto 1) := p1(b'length-2 downto 0);
>             p1(0) := a1(a'length-1);
>             a1(a'length-1 downto 1) := a1(a'length-2 downto 0);
>             p1 := p1-b1;
>             if(p1(b'length-1) ='1') then
>                 a1(0) :='0';
>                 p1 := p1+b1;
>             else
>                 a1(0) :='1';
>             end if;
>         end loop;
>         return to_integer(a1);
>     end divide;
> ```

Comment: Division is always a bit more difficult than multiplication. Think about multiplying by the reciprocal and getting the reciprocal of the divisor from a look up table.

Comment: Maybe "variable b1 : unsigned(15 downto 0):=b;" instead of ...":=a"

Comment: Are your inputs (dividend and divisor) both variables ? Doing a 1 cycle divider is possible, but it will work at low frequency and occupy a lot of area (well, of course, it depends on the width of the operands...).

Comment: One cycle latency, or one cycle throughput?

Comment: One cycle latency. I fixed my code with the suggestion that @TEMLIB made but now I am using more resources than my FPGA can handle. How could I use less recources in my code?

Comment: One cycle latency 16 bits divider is a really bad idea. It requires 16 consecutive adders, which means a lot of area and a very long critical path. If you can live with an approximation, multiplying by inverse would be better, but for 16 bits requires a lot of ROM... Some division algorithm should yield smaller circuit (like SRT-4) and faster division, but requires the MSB of divider to be alway '1'.

Comment: when you say approximation, what do you mean? I will not be getting a float so rounding up is OK. Multiplying by the inverse would be inverting the integer and multiplying, right? @JonathanDrolet

Comment: By approximation, I mean you won't get the exact value but pretty close to it. This is because a lot of inverse can't be represented exactly in binary. The overall precision depends your precision on the inverse representation (thus, size of ROM and multiplier). For example, if you want to do 12345/45 (should give 274) and give 16bits to represent 1/45 (1456), the result of get of multiplying by inverse is 278. You would get a smaller error by using a ROM of more than 16 bits.

Comment: How big would I need a multiplier to be to get 274 instead of 278 for your example? I am designing a processor in VHDL and accuracy is important to that extent. @JonathanDrolet

Comment: You would have to make that analysis by yourself, but for no error for a 16 by 16 bits divider: very big. Every processor out there performs division in multiple cycles, in the order of 1 clock cycle per bit. Smaller processor don't have an hardware divider, they rely on software implementation (a lot slower). Generally, compiler and good programmer avoid division at all cost since it is inherently slow. If you wish to add a single latency divider to your processor, all other operations would be slower as a result of the larger critical path.

Comment: Not so applicable to this question, but for the benefit of Googlers: division by a power of two is very cheap in hardware, it just involves shifting bits to the right.

Comment: So what are the logical steps to have no error, one cycle latency 16-bit division? I will be dividing by somewhat random numbers. everything from 0 to 65535.

Comment: @JonathanDrolet I got it to work, the code above I mean. The division now gives me a different result every time! why?

Answer (score 5):

This answer isn't what you're looking for, but the basic solution to this problem is this: *Don't use division*.

Many processor architectures and even DSP chips do not have a division instruction at all, and where they do have division, it is usually a multi-cycle operation, because division is fundamentally iterative. Division is expensive in terms of area, and slow, so it is usually avoided if possible.

I strongly suggest that yourself or anybody reading this question tries very hard to avoid implementing a hardware divide function of any sort, let alone a single-cycle one. As some comments have said, the standard approach would be to implement a multiplication by the reciprocal of the divisor. Even here, if you expect good performance in your FPGA, this would be implemented using a pipelined architecture, and so would not have single-cycle latency.

An even better solution would be to revise your design such that there is no need for any division or an equivalent. However, without knowing what your design is supposed to do, it's impossible to suggest alternatives.

As a footnote, and as a comment noted, division by a power of two is relatively simple, because it boils down to a shift operation.

Comment: I will still NEED to do division. how would I do multi-cycle division? I am making a processor in an fpga and division will be more than necessary. Code is not required, but preferred. Sorry to bother you again.

Comment: I suggest you create a working processor, and implement a division routine in software. This is what has been done in most processor designs for decades. Programmers are mostly aware that 'divide' is expensive, and would not put this operation in an inner loop or other critical code section. You could always go back and add some hardware division support later, if this turned out to be a real bottleneck in your application.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm you gave originally is a 'restoring division' algorithm; it requires one clock cycle for each bit of the quotient. Non-restoring division is normally used in hardware; this also takes one cycle per bit of the quotient. There are about a billion Google hits on non-restoring division. It's simple, but a bit fiddly - give it a go and ask if/when it doesn't work.

Don't even think about invert/multiply unless the dividend is a constant, in which case it's easy and fast, and won't even require a multiplier (you can use adders instead).